# session is not set in magento

Tags: magento-1.9, session

i am using **magento 1.9** and i am try to **set session** **out side magento file**.
my problem is **session**  set but when i`m try to **get session** in **view.phtml** page it show result null.

this is my code:

```
set_time_limit(0);
ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');   
define('MAGENTO_ROOT', getcwd());
$mageFilename = MAGENTO_ROOT . '/app/Mage.php';
require_once $mageFilename;
Mage::init();
$ponumber = "123456";
Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->setPonumber($ponumber); 
$getponumber = Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getPonumber();
echo "ponumber->".$getponumber; // its print 123456
```

**view.pthml**

```
$ponumber= '';
$ponumber= Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getPonumber();
echo "----->".$ponumber."<-----";
```

what am i doing wrong.

**Any help or suggestion will be appreciated.**

Answer (score 0):

use these for session

```
Mage::app();
Mage::getSingleton('core/session', array('name' => 'frontend'));
$write = Mage::getSingleton ('core/resource')->getConnection('core_write');
```

[reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9048180/how-do-i-create-a-magento-session-outside-of-magento)

Comment: no change, same result(NULL).

Comment: updated the answer and also added the reference.

Comment: @DhavalDave i test your code and it's working after adding these.

Comment: i try this in external magento file  and view.phtml ,var_dump(Mage::getSingleton('core/session')); its show session external magento file but not in view.phtml

Comment: @DhavalDave this code i use and it worked `require_once 'app/Mage.php';
umask(0);
Mage::app();
Mage::getSingleton('core/session', array('name' => 'frontend'));
$write = Mage::getSingleton ('core/resource')->getConnection('core_write');`